# Why does this code not throw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I expected the following lines of code to throw an exception since I am accessing the `Value` property of a nullable variable that is assigned a value of `null`. However, I do not get any exception when I execute the below:

```
int? x=null;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value==null);
```

But when I do:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
```

I do get an exception, as could be expected.

But what is the difference between the 2 ways of accessing `x.Value`? Why do I not get an exception in the first case? Both pieces of code are after all trying to access the x.Value property.

Note: I am running the above pieces of code on the [www.compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com) website, btw. Not sure if trying on the Visual Studio compiler would yield different results, but I do not have access to Visual Studio currently.

TIA.

Comment: The Console.WriteLine(x.Value==null); also throws Invalid operationexception.

Comment: Both throws an exception.

Comment: compileonline.com uses the Mono compiler, not Microsoft's. I think you may have found a bug in that compiler.

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in the online compiler.

Comment: I get: Warning as Error: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?' So maybe its an optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the [website compile online](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php) you point out, the mono compile does a rewrite/optimalization of your code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? x=null;
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value==null);  //-> Console.WriteLine(false);    
    }
}
```

---

> Compiling the source code....
>
> $mcs main.cs -out:demo.exe 2>&1
>
> main.cs(9,38): warning CS0472: The result of comparing value type `int' with null is`false'
>
> Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
>
> Executing the program....
>
> $mono demo.exe
>
> False

warning CS0472 tell you that, it is a bug in the online/mono compiler they are using.

Comment: -1 because the warning doesn't tell you that `x.Value` doesn't get evaluated, the warning only tells you that the comparison with `null` will never return `true`.

Comment: If the code is not rewritten by the compiler, it would have failed with an exception on runtime, however it does not fail on runtime. The used mono compiler has a bug, the Microsoft compiler will give you a different result.

Comment: The warning says the code retrieves `x.Value`, discards it, and prints `false`. The actual behaviour is that `false` is printed *without* retrieving `x.Value`. So, no, the warning still doesn't tell you that.

Comment: @peer: thanks for pointing out the fact about the rewrite done by the mono compiler. It does seem buggy behavior by the compiler to not check for possible exceptions from the code before doing an optimization rewrite on it.

Answer (score 5):

Both code throws [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) because

From [`Nullable<T>.Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx)

> The value of the current `Nullable<T>` object if the `HasValue` property
>   is `true`. **An exception is thrown if the HasValue property is false**.

In your both case, [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property will be false. That's why both code throws [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

**EDIT**: Okey okey.. Looks like [*www.compileonline.com*](http://www.compileonline.com/) website uses Mono 2.10.2.0 and first code gives just warning like;

> main.cs(9,34): warning CS0472: The result of comparing value type
>   `int' with null is`false'

I checked out [Bug Fixes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#Bug_Fixes) page but I couldn't find anything about this issue. Keep searching..

Looks like in *Mono 2.10.2.0* even if [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is false, this code doesn't throw exception. It just gives warning.

From [`Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0472`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228621%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The result of the expression is always 'value1' since a value of type
>   'value2' is never equal to 'null' of type 'value3'

So in our case, looks like *Mono 2.10.2.0* checks out `x` is `int?` but `x.Value` is `int` and it says like (instead throwing exception);

> this is an `int` and it is a *value type*, it never be equal to `null`.

**EDIT2**: [hdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) has a point I think. This seems related with [Bug 12608](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12608) which is fixed in *Mono 3.1.10* but I couldn't be sure about that.

Still keep searching..

**EDIT3**: Ok.. I tried these code on [`Ideone`](http://ideone.com/), and in [`sample page`](http://ideone.com/samples) it says it uses *Mono 2.8* for C# compiler, and results are **surprising**..

Your [`first example`](http://ideone.com/T67wBF);

```
int? x = null;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value == null);
```

it doesn't throw any exception and **it doesn't even show any warning either**. It just works perfectly and generates `False` as a result. Looks like it doesn't check `HasValue` property and it doesn't even look the root of `Nullable<T>` (which is `int` in our case) is *value type* or not.

Your [`second example`](http://ideone.com/sV2LTL);

```
int? x = null;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
```

throws `InvalidOperationException` as we are expected.

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object
>   must have a value.   at System.Nullable`1[System.Int32].get_Value ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Test.Main () [0x00000] in
>   :0

### Wait a second..

In [`first example`](http://ideone.com/T67wBF), we said;

> *Looks like it doesn't check `HasValue` property..*

How even possible it checks `HasValue` property in this time? I think this is a online compiler bug but still I couldn't check it on *Mono 3.+* version..

**EDIT4**: I send a message the guy who created this site from it's *[contact page](http://www.compileonline.com/contact.php)* and explian this situation.

Comment: The question says that the first code does not throw an exception, and asks why. How is this an answer to that question?

Comment: This is possibly a different manifestation of [bug 12608](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12608), fixed in Mono 3.1.1 (according to its release notes). I don't have Mono installed here to check that, though.

Comment: @hvd _Hmm_, yes this can be relevant with this bug. I don't have Mono also either that's why I couldn't check it. Added my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar How about now?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler you use wrongly optimizes away the call to the property `get` accessor. This code reproduces the bug, with that compiler:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Prop == null);
    }

    static int Prop
    { 
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("This error must be!"); 
        } 
    }
}
```

The Visual C# compiler does not have this bug. But it has bad warning texts in some cases. Try changing `int` to `DateTime`, and `==` to `>` in my code, and see warning text from Visual C# compiler.